# How to create dynamic search filter in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a search filter in reactjs, I've tried bind method to `onChange´ event but it triggered for every single letter. How can it make it work to after type 3 letters.

```
    

     var FilteredList = React.createClass({
      filterList: function(event){
        var updatedList = this.state.initialItems;
        updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item){
          return item.toLowerCase().search(
            event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
        this.setState({items: updatedList});
      },
      getInitialState: function(){
         return {
           initialItems: [
             "Apples",
             "Broccoli",
             "Chicken",
             "Duck",
             "Eggs",
             "Fish",
             "Granola",
             "Hash Browns"
           ],
           items: []
         }
      },
      componentWillMount: function(){
        this.setState({items: this.state.initialItems})
      },
      render: function(){
        return (
          <div className="filter-list">
            <form>
            <fieldset className="form-group">
            <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.filterList}/>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
          <List items={this.state.items}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
    
    var List = React.createClass({
      render: function(){
        return (
          <ul className="list-group">
          {
            this.props.items.map(function(item) {
              return <li className="list-group-item" data-category={item} key={item}>{item}</li>
            })
           }
          </ul>
        )  
      }
    });
    
    React.render(<FilteredList/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

https://codepen.io/mtclmn/pen/QyPVJp, i tried to change this code for my case but im stuck with triggering it after 3 letters scenario.

Any idea would be much appreciate.

Comment: Please share what you have already tried. Perhaps something as simple as not triggering the search function until 3 characters are on the input box would be a simple trick to achieve the same.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Samridh Tuladhr, code example added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` is triggered whenever the `event` happened. So when `even.target.value` as values `input` tag is changed then function is activated. Unlike Other methods like onClick or onSubmit that is activated after clicking or clicking the submit button, every change is detected by `onChange` event. That's how different between `onChange` and `onClick`. If you want to search after typing 3 letters then there is an easy one approach. Setting condition `value.length >= 3` would be helpful.

https://codepen.io/jacobkim9881/pen/LYRjLwd

Comment: Even thought it seems straight forward, but once the user clears the field, We must get back the original list of select items which is not happening here :) in your code yet https://codepen.io/jacobkim9881/pen/LYRjLwd

Comment: As @Imran Rafiq Rather who is a nice React dev kindly cleared above, the demonstration is above :)

Answer (score 1):

As the function which is pass to the onChange property of an input field is called any time you type on the keyboard. You can check inside of that function before performing any change which you need as updating the state If the value of event.target.value length is greather or equal to 3 like this

```
filterList: function(event){
    if(event.target.value.length >= 3) {
       // Here you can perform what you need
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified your `filterList` function to only start the searching when there are 3 characters available, otherwise, return the `initialItems` list :

```
filterList: function(event){
    if(event.target.value.length > 2){
    var updatedList = this.state.initialItems;
    updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item){
      return item.toLowerCase().search(
        event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    this.setState({items: updatedList});
    }
    else{
      console.log(this.state.initialItems)
      this.setState({items: this.state.initialItems})
    }
  }
```

Edit: the previous answer posted here, is doing the same as me. I have added an additional `else` condition to return the entire list when there is nothing on the search bar. Please change it to `else if` to suit your requirements.